# How do I customize the grub2 menu via terminal, in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: grub2, customization

I would like to customize the Grub2 Menu without programs like "Grub Customization"?

PS: This program may be good but not for this PC, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean by customize? adding a new menu entry? changing default settings?

Answer (score 0):

For the manual customization of the GRUB menu, use the `40_custom` script file located in the `/etc/grub.d/` directory. Comment out the line `exec tail -n +3 $0`. Scroll down a little bit and add the following lines after all the comments: `cat << EOF\nEOF`. The file now should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
cat << EOF
    # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
EOF
```

Place your menu entry code between `cat << EOF` and `EOF`.

To customize any existing menu entries, use the files `10_linux` and `20_linux_xen`.